# Is it possible to extend Linphone call log history limit?

Tags: windows, linphone, linphone-sdk

Today I noticed the call history on Linphone is limited to 30 entries. I want to get the last 100 entries.

Is there any way to have a bigger call log history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the 'history_max_size' in file 'linphonerc_factory' in your project to whatever you want, I change this value to 200~

Comment: It should be set to config file and it works. Thanks